# Twillio outbount user creation

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I need to add user as a outbound caller ID. By using the following code

```
const accountSid = 'ACeae3abf5038c91052c27aa2a04969457';
const authToken = 'AUTH_TOKEN';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.outgoingCallerIds
.create({
friendlyName: '918606488880',
phoneNumber: '+919020044692',
})
.then((callerId) => process.stdout.write(callerId.sid));
```

Then I get the following error message like

```
 .create({
 ^
TypeError: client.outgoingCallerIds.create is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jose/test/twillio/callerid.js:6:4)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:505:3
```

The above code is got from the documentation of twillio [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/outgoing-caller-ids)

Actualy my requirement is to send voice calls to defferent users. So I need to add the users in to my outbound caller ID's.

Comment: What version of the Twilio Node module are you using?

Comment: node version 6.9.4

Comment: What's the version of the Twilio npm module?

Answer (score 2):

It seems likely, especially if you did a fresh `npm install twilio` that you would have installed the latest 3.x version of the [node helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node). The page you linked to above still defaults to 2.x version code. You can click 3.x in the upper right of the sandbox to find:

```
client.api.accounts(accountSid)
  .outgoingCallerIds('OutgoingCallerIdSid')
  .fetch()
  .then((callerId) => console.log(callerId.phoneNumber));
```

Comment: Everything works fine with updating the node version.